# How to know the number of ways to remove edges from a connected graph so that all the nodes have an even degree?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory

Let's say we have an undirected graph G, where V = number of nodes and E = number of edges. In this graph, there are vertices with odd degrees as well as even degrees, but I have to transform the graph to one with only even degree nodes and I can do that by removing some edges. How do we find the number of ways to remove the edges so that there are no nodes with odd degrees left (this could also mean removing all edges altogether)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edited, and thanks for the reply. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Exchange. Nice problem!!  Are you looking for an algorithm to remove the edges and arrive at some solution, or an enumeration of the number of possible solutions?  I can at least give you a start - remove all the edges connected to any vertex of degree one. Repeat this until you can't any more.

Comment: Yea, but well, I'm looking for an algorithm that will give me the number of ways I can remove certain edges so that I come to a graph with no odd degrees, one solution will always be to have no edges at all (0 is even). I know that from handshake theorem there can only be even numbers of odd degree vertices.

Comment: To count the number of ways, you will need to specify whether the order in which they're deleted matters, or is it purely the number of possible finished graphs that are counted.

Comment: @samerivertwice the order doesn't matter we only need the number of ways

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_postman_problem